# How to set small icon size for`tinymce` in mobile screens?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I added `tinymce4-lite` in my Django application. The size of icons looks the same in bigger screens and small screens.

Big Screens:

[image]

Small Screens:

[image]

the size of icons are similar in either big and small screens. I want it to be smaller and more elegant in mobile size screens.

This is the configuration in `settings.py`:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'menubar': False,
    'statusbar': False,
    'width': '100%',
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample | hr visualchars |  
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'remove_linebreaks': False
}
```

Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TinyMCE 4 there is a setting called `toolbar_items_size` that allows you to set the icons on the toolbar to a smaller size:

```
toolbar_items_size: 'small'
```

Please note that this is no longer valid in TinyMCE 5 but it will work if you are using TinyMCE 4.

Comment: Thank you Michael Fromin, it works good. What is the solution for TinyMCE 5

Comment: TinyMCE 5 has a skins and icons pack that includes smaller icons.  This is a paid/premium option.  Alternatively you can make your own skins/icons as documented in the TinyMCE documentation:  
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#icons
and https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-an-icon-pack/